# what happens when I query an empty Table when using custom Spring JPA repository

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, repository

The table's structure is as follows:

> FILE_NAME
>
> FILE_TYPE
>
> FILE_SIZE
>
> CREATED_DATA

The query is:

```
@Query("Select f.fileSize from FileEntity e where f.fileType =:fileType 
order by f.createdDate limit 1")
Long findFileSize(@Param("fileType") String fileType);
```

This is a query that returns the file size of the latest file stored in dB.

What will this query return if the table is empty. Will it return the default value of Long or throw an Exception?

Comment: This will return you null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return NULL. therfore, LONG wrapper class can be used to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

If the table has no rows, then the query will return no rows.  This is the same if there are rows and the `where` clause filters all of them out.

If you try to access a value in the result set without first checking if a row exists, you'll probably get an error.

Comment: In this case , I am trying to access the file_size of the 1st row fetched. So, will it return a error ?

Comment: It will return NULL